# Trigger second journey only after completing the first journey

Tags: marketing-cloud

How to trigger journey after completion of another journey. Is it possible ??

Comment: Do you need to do it in real time? Or can a slight delay (e.g. 1 hour) be acceptable?

Comment: I want do it in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this in real time, you will need to build a custom JB activity, which uses REST API to trigger the next journey. The drawback of this solution, apart from requiring substantial coding, is the fact that your journey 2 will have an API trigger, and hence will not be able to run scheduled or based timed with an automation run.

You can read about custom JB activities [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm).

And about triggering journeys with API [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-to-fire-an-event.htm).

Comment: You are welcome. Remember to mark the answer as accepted.